# rubyでの配列の引数の渡し方

Tags: ruby

rubyでメソッドの引数を可変長引数(*変数名)で定義して、それに対して二次元配列を渡しているのですが、nilが返ってきてうまくいきません。
二次元配列をそのままメソッドに投げたい時はどういう方法がいいのか知りたいです。

#### 追記

ソースコードです

```
def calc(*array)
    puts "array"
end

array = [[01,10,11],[02,20,21]]
calc(array)
```

Comment: どのようなcodeを書かれてるのか分からないと有効な回答は返って来ないと思います。自身で書かれているcodeを質問文に載せてみてはいかがですか？

Comment: `array = [[01,10,11],[02,20,21]]

calc(array)

def calc(*array)
puts "array"
end`のようなコードの時にうまくいきません

Comment: 「うまくいかない」とは具体的にどういう意味ですか。どういう処理をしたときにどういう結果を期待しているのか、質問を編集して追記してください

Answer (score 1, accepted):

calcからnilが返ってくるのはputsの戻り値が返ってきてるだけですよ。

ruby は明示的にreturnを書く必要がありません。が、その時、返されるのは最後に評価した結果です。
なので、配列を返してあげたいのであればmethodの最後に配列を使ってあげれば良いだけです。

```
array = [[01,10,11],[02,20,21]]
def calc(*array)
  array.each{ |a| p a }
  array
end
calc(*array)
```

イマイチ、nilが返ってくるのが問題なのか、calc内でarrayを使えてないのが問題なのか分かりませんが、上記のようなcodeで所望の動きは得られますか？

---

ちょっとcode変えました。こっちの方が分かりやすいかな？